# How to change AuthenticationLevel attribute from Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting class using powershell?

Tags: powershell, wmi, dcom

I'm trying to change the AuthenticationLevel attribute from Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting using the following poweshell code:

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter "AppID='{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'" -EnableAllPrivileges
$wmi.AuthenticationLevel = 1
```

The script runs without errors, but the change isn't applyed in DCOM configurations.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

Just call the put method from $wmi instance.

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter "AppID='{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'" -EnableAllPrivileges
$wmi.AuthenticationLevel = 2
$wmi.put()
```